# sql/oracle select values seperated by comma with grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

I have first table like this: table_1

| date | group_number | c_id | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | A | 001 | 12.0 |
| 02.01.2020 | A | 001 | 12.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | A | 002 | 10.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | B | 103 | 8.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | B | 101 | 8.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | C | 203 | 11.0 |

And have second table_2 with name of group with date of records:

| date | group_number |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | A |
| 02.02.2020 | A |
| 03.03.2020 | A |
| 01.01.2020 | B |
| 01.02.2020 | B |
| 01.01.2020 | C |

The task is to write to new column in table_2 the rates of each c_id seperated by comma, grouped by group_number. I need to add new column to table_2 as next:

| date | group_number | rate_for_groups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | A | 12.0, 10.0 |
| 02.02.2020 | A | 12.0, 10.0 |
| 03.03.2020 | A | 12.0, 10.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | B | 8.0, 8.0 |
| 01.02.2020 | B | 8.0, 8.0 |
| 01.01.2020 | C | 11.0 |

I have tried to do smth like this:

```
select *,    
  listagg(rate, ',') within group (order by C_ID) as rates
from table_1
group by group_number
```

but it raised the error "not a group by expression"

Comment: select date, group_number, .. group by date, group_number

Comment: After posting my answer, I see that I may not have understood the task correctly. Why are you showing `8.0, 8.0` for all B rows, but `12.0, 10.0` rather than `12.0, 12.0, 10.0` for the A rows? Does the date come into play here? If so, how exactly?

Comment: becuz in A row there are two same c_id's, in B the c_id's are different so 8.0 are added twice.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): ***Cause**: The GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the SELECT clause. SELECT expressions that are not included in a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.* It is quite clear description.

Answer (score 0):

Your query shows only half the task: You are only looking at `table_1`. With `GROUP BY group_number` you tell the DBMS to select one row per `group_number` only. That is fine for that table. But you cannot `SELECT *` then, because there are several rows per `group_number`. How is the DBMS supposed to know which row's values to display then for a `group_number`?

Remove the `*` from that query to get it valid. select the `group_number` instead. Then join this result to `table_2`.

```
select *
from table_2 t2
left outer join
(
  select
    group_number,
    listagg(rate, ',') within group (order by c_id) as rates
  from table_1
  group by group_number
) t1 on t1.group_number = t2.group_number
order by t2.group_number, t2.date;
```